# How to modify thickness of existing graphics in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, svg

I have an existing svg image:

[image: thought-bubble image from svgrepo.com]

source: https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/165174/thought-bubble

And I'd like to modify the thickness of lines to be a bit slimmer. How could I achieve that in Inkscape?

The manuals suggest editing stroke and fill but I can't seem to find any way to have these attributes influence the image.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. `path->inset` (`ctrl+)`) did it!

[image]